# How to play an asx into wordpress sidebar?

Tags: wordpress, widget, asx

I'm searching for a widget that can play an asx file into wordpress sidebar. If this widget  exists, where can i find it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this: 
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/embedded-video-with-link/

I've used it past version 2.6 of wordpress and it works fine.